# How to define a partial copy constructor metaprogramically in Julia?

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

Gadfly has a nifty macro that generates a copy constructor and optional argument constructor for some large types:

```
# Generate large types where each field has a default value to which it's
# initialized.

macro varset(name::Symbol, table)
    @assert table.head == :block
    table = table.args

    names = Any[]
    vars = Any[]
    parameters = Any[]
    parameters_expr = Expr(:parameters)

    for row in table
        if isa(row, Expr) && row.head == :line
            continue
        end

        if isa(row, Symbol)
            var = row
            typ = :Any
            default = :nothing
        elseif row.head == :tuple
            @assert 2 <= length(row.args) <= 3
            var = row.args[1]
            typ = row.args[2]
            default = length(row.args) > 2 ? row.args[3] : :nothing
        else
            error("Bad varset systax")
        end

        push!(names, var)
        push!(vars, :($(var)::$(typ)))
        push!(parameters, Expr(:kw, var, default))
        parameters_expr = Expr(:parameters, parameters...)
    end

    new_with_defaults = Expr(:call, :new, names...)

    ex =
    quote
        type $(name)
            $(vars...)

            function $(name)($(parameters_expr))
                $(new_with_defaults)
            end

            # shallow copy constructor
            function $(name)(a::$(name))
                b = new()
                for name in fieldnames($(name))
                    setfield!(b, name, getfield(a, name))
                end
                b
            end
        end

        function copy(a::$(name))
            $(name)(a)
        end
    end

    esc(ex)
end
```

I would like to add a partial copy constructor that lets you provide an object and some partial parameters. It would copy the provided object and overwrite only the fields that you give it.

How could I define something like the following? Pseudocode-ish:

```
function $(name)(a::$(name), $(parameters_expr))
            b = new(a)
            for name in names
                if getfield(b, name) != default
                    setfield!(b, name, new_val)
                end
            end
        end
```

Comment: Do you care about performance? You could easily do something with keyword arguments, but I suspect performance will break down with too many fields.

Comment: Gadfly is already using a huge list of keywords and this type only get constructed once or twice. Performance isn't that important.